# Use of undeclared type 'JSONDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm working on a project in Swift 2.3 and I'm using the AlamoFire framework and SwiftyJSON as to implement my webserver call methods.

Thus I have written a singleton class as to call these server call functions wherever I want in my project.

Hence for instance once the login button is tapped the login function in this class will execute.

But when I build and run the project and once the login button is tapped the app crashes and I'm getting an issue denoting

> Use of Undeclared type 'JSONDictionary'.

The code as bellow and the line I'm getting issue is marked with a comment.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

struct Singleton {
  static let instance : APIManager = APIManager()
}


public class APIManager: NSObject {

    var appURLs = AppURLs.sharedInstance



  public class var sharedInstance: APIManager {
    return Singleton.instance
  }

  let manager = Manager()

  override init() {

  }
func login(username: String, password: String, completion: (user: User, success: Bool) -> (), failed:(error: NSError) -> ()) -> Request {

    let baseURL = NSURL(string: appURLs.mainBaseURL);
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: baseURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(appURLs.loginURL)!)
 return manager.request(urlRequest)

      .validate()
      .responseJSON { response in
        if let error = response.result.error {
          failed(error: error)
          print(error)
          return;
        }
        print("working up to here")
        let ok = ((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["success"] as? Bool)!//This is where I get the issue
        if ok {
        let userJson = JSON((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["user"]!)

        let token = ((response.result.value as! JSONDictionary)["token"] as? String)!
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(token, forKey: "TOKEN")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        //let user = user(json: userJson)
        let user = User()
        user.displayName = userJson ["displayName"].string
        print("displayName is :", user.displayName)

        completion(user: user,success: ok)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast what you get from Alamofire to `Dictionary` or `[String: AnyObject]`.

Here's a sample code to handle the response value you get:

```
// You can add "as? [String:AnyObject]" to the if let statement if you prefer.
if let jsonResult = response.result.value { // jsonResult is of type [String: AnyObject]
    let jsonObj = JSON(jsonResult)

    print(jsonObj)
}
```

Then from your jsonObj, you can do something like `jsonObj["user"]["token"].string` to retrieve the token (don't forget to protect this call with a `if let` or `guard let` to make sure the value isn't `nil`

EDIT: Here's what your code would look like:

```
// you need to change the keys to what the API expect
return manager.request(.POST, urlRequest, parameters: ["userName": username, "password": password], encoding: .JSON)

  .validate()
  .responseJSON { response in
    if let error = response.result.error {
      failed(error: error)
      print(error)
      return;
    }
    print("working up to here")
    if let jsonResult = response.result.value {
        let jsonObj = JSON(jsonResult)

        print(jsonObj)
        let ok = jsonObj["success"].bool // or boolValue

        if ok != false {
            if let token = jsonObj["user"]["token"].string {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(token, forKey: "TOKEN")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            }

            let user = User()
            user.displayName = jsonObj["user"]["displayName"].string
            print("displayName is :", user.displayName)

            completion(user: user,success: ok)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im sorry im new to swift, so which line I should get rid of and where to place this code

Comment: Edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: Im not getting the success response from the jsonObj. Any idea why is that ?

Comment: What does the `print(jsonObj)` show? Do you have a "success" key to your JSON response?

Comment: Json response : {
  "validation" : {
    "auth" : false
  },
  "result" : {
    "message" : "information_error"
  }
}

Comment: from what I see in your code, you didn't send the username and password with your request. That might be why your authentication fail. Is it a POST / GET request?

Comment: It is a post request Sir

Comment: I changed my answer again to show how the request should be changed (don't forget to change the `parameters` Dictionary with the keys that your API need)

Comment: i used my parameters and edit the code but still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: hm without knowing more about the API and what is the expected JSON when the user successfully logs in, I can't really help more.

Answer (score 1):

There's just a type alias missing

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:AnyObject] // Swift 3: [String:Any]
```

Put the line in the `APIManager` class

---

And you can replace

```
struct Singleton {
  static let instance : APIManager = APIManager()
}


public class APIManager: NSObject {

  var appURLs = AppURLs.sharedInstance

  public class var sharedInstance: APIManager {
    return Singleton.instance
  }
...
```

with

```
public class APIManager: NSObject {

    var appURLs = AppURLs.sharedInstance
    static let sharedInstance = APIManager()
...
```

The `Singleton` stuff is outdated and not needed anymore.

---

PS: **Do not** use `setValue:forKey:` to save an object in user defaults. The correct method is `setObject:forKey:`